# What different types of dye are there?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There are many types of dye, but all I know are black, red, yellow and green. What else is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dye), there are two divisions of dyes, primary and secondary. The primary dyes are:

- Rose red
- Orange dye
- Dandelion yellow
- Cactus green
- Lapis lazuli
- Light blue dye
- Magenta dye
- Pink dye
- Bone meal
- Light grey dye
- Ink sac
- Cocoa beans

The secondary dyes include:

- Cyan dye
- Purple dye
- Grey dye
- Lime dye